# how to make the NAME and TITLE similar of all audio/music files in a folder at once (windows 7 ultimate)?

Tags: windows-registry

I want to rename all the TITLE of music (audio/mp3) files similar to its NAME in a particular folder. However, i can do it to a single file at a time. But there are thousands of mp3 files and it will be boring as well as will take long time to do the job individually for each file. So, i am searching for advice or name of a software to do the job at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Flexible Renamer](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA014830/english/FlexRena/) years ago. Now I use [Jaikoz](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/) for everything tag-related.

Answer (score 1):

MP3Tag is free and works like a champ. You can regex tags and synch between tags and filenames. Used it on 1000-file+ directories.

http://www.mp3tag.de/en/